# Is there any association between public IP and secondary alias IP in google compute engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to implement a HA solution for my product in GCP, where I want to move secondary alias IP and public IP from active to standby node on switchover. For this purpose, I want all traffic coming on public IP of an interface should land on secondary alias IP address. What I observed is: the traffic coming on a public ip is landing on primary private ip address.  So is there any way we can bind public IP to alias IP..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, but you can handle the `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` headers that Google's load balancers should be passing you How to do that depends a bit on the software you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement an HA solution in GCP, there are other alternatives that can help you to make this implementation easier than rely on solutions that are usually used  in on-premise platforms.

The implementation that you are trying sounds more like [VRRP redundancy](https://packetpushers.net/vrrp-linux-using-keepalived-2/) with linux. Instead I encouraging you read this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-floating-ip-addresses) that is gives some options when working with VIP's and HA environments.